# User selects another tab, the page title changes to a different title every 8 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the title of a tab based on a timer.

I have found an example online but can't get it to work, also i don't know if it supports multiple page titles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.
min.js"> 
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
$(function() {

    var origTitle, animatedTitle, timer;

    function animateTitle(newTitle) {
        var currentState = false;
        origTitle = document.title; // save original title
        animatedTitle = "Hey There! " + origTitle;
        timer = setInterval(startAnimation, 20);

        function startAnimation() {
            // animate between the original and the new title
            document.title = currentState ? origTitle : animatedTitle;
            currentState = !currentState;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is fine, if you want to change the title every 8 seconds make sure you set `setInterval` to use `8000` milliseconds instead of `20` and make sure something makes the initial call to `animateTitle('YourTitle');`

Comment: ok thanks, don't know why it's not working then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that changes the title every 8 seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var counter = 0;
        setInterval( function () {
            counter = counter + 1;
            document.title = "Iteration: " + counter;
        }, 8000 );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For use within your Script.js file in combination with jQuery, you might want to wrap it all in `$(document).ready( function() {...} );`

**Update**
Here's an example for displaying a different name every 8 seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Hello there!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var names = [ "Rick", "Michonne", "Darryl", "Rosita", "Negan" ];
        var counter = 0;
        setInterval( function () {
            document.title = "Hello " + names[ counter ];
            if ( counter == names.length - 1 ) {
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }, 8000 );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great thanks, I'm just wondering if it's possible to choose the title name using the same code? `document.title = "Iteration1","Iteration2","Iteration3" ;`

Comment: Is there a fixed set of names?

Comment: Yeh the names are fixed

Comment: I updated answer. The counter increment is now after the ```document.title``` part because we want to start at 0 and increment after displaying the first name.